# How can I deploy a Python script and its dependencies (no Internet connection)?

Tags: python, package, pyinstaller, portability, python-poetry

I have a production PC that won't have a decent Internet connection (e.g. let's say just the bare 'apt-get install ....', definitely no pip3)

So I develop on a similar Linux OS/environment for the everyday work, but I'll push it to the final machine in the more portable way, if possible, in a standalone way (e.g. no need to install anything)

My Python environment was initiated with Poetry, Python 3, half a dozen of packages/lib/modules (snmp, hexdump, tftp, coloredlogs, pcap, etc.), trying to keep it PEP8 clean and now I would like to copy ([rsync](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync)) my work to the production machine in a few weeks without having to unroll the whole packages & deps installation.

Did I just describe Docker? It sounds like such an overkill for what I want to achieve.

I was hoping to have poetry to take care of this, but even poetry seems to be only pip-available.

Shall I list and download my packages and dependencies manually and install them manually? (But the pip 3 installation on that machine must be so old, I feel I'll hit dependencies waterfalls.)

Did I google that badly that I missed *the*  best practice for such a common scenario?

I am eager to read your best hints!

Comment: So the best practice I know of, is to use a `.yaml` file to export your enviroment. Have you tried that already?

Comment: Well, sure: poetry is based on a .toml and a .lock (with all modules & deps.) but I am confident I could end-up with a decent .yaml. But then I am afraid of what I'll have to do based on that .yaml (I am guessing any kind of 'install' procedure will try and pull package from the net, right?)

Comment: Please omit editorial content out when asking questions here. Focus on the _actual question_, not how you feel about it. Emoji and emoticons are rarely appropriate, and sexual language is _certainly_ not welcome.

Comment: Do you have a stable intranet that is accessible between the dev and prod machines?

Comment: Yes: that's the way I ssh/rsync, but won't have an internet gtw routed through this :P